# How to rename a console window in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, console-application, rename

I had made a CLI Python programme using socket and I want to rename my Console Window to "Single Server Chat".
It would be great of you to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will change the title of command prompt in windows.

```
import os
os.system('title "Single Server Chat"')
```